# Error:(49) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

While I was trying to compile my code outta nowhere I got this bug!
The below code is my Login activity's layout.
I have no idea about this error.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#ffff"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
        android:hint="@string/placeholder_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:="@+id/signinPassword"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: What the hell do you try to achieve with this "screenshot"? And why the hell is it censored? It doesn't add any value to your question.

Comment: @Clijsters Just highlighted the important parts. And i censored the other code as i thought of doing that!

Comment: @VivekGadhvi - Just curious; why did you unaccept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `android:="@+id/signinPassword"` doesn't have a name after the `android:` namespace prefix.

It should look something like `android:attr="@+id/signinPassword"` (replace `attr` with the correct attribute name; maybe `id`?).

Comment: My guess: it should be `android:id`

Comment: @JoopEggen - That's what I meant by "_replace `attr` with the correct attribute name; maybe `id`?_".